# Copying and positioning of a picture from sheet 1 to sheet 2

Tags: vba, excel

I am programming a calculator. On sheet, *calculator* options are configured ("x" and "y") and after pressing the *showdata* button, data is copied from sheet *overview* and displayed in sheet *calculator*.

Every configuration option has its own picture. These pictures are also listed in the sheet *overview*.

Corresponding to the chosen configuration, the relevant picture should be copied from sheet *overview* to sheet *calculator* and positioned at cell *D5*. If there is another older picture in the sheet *calculator* it has to be deleted. That means pressing the *showdata* button is supposed to work like an actualization button for the relevant data and picture.

How can I copy and position a picture under the above mentioned circumstances? 
You find the working code segment for the data copying process below.

```
Public Sub showdata_click()

    Dim x As String
    Dim y As String

    x = Sheets("calculator").Range("B3").Value
    y = Sheets("calculator").Range("B4").Value

    '----------copying M5005 with C120 ------------------------------
    If x = "M5005" And y = "C120" Then
        Sheets("overview").Range("B17:B33").Copy
        Sheets("calculator").Range("B11.B27").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If

    '----------copying M5005 with C125 -------------------------------
    If x = "M5005" And y = "C125" Then
        Sheets("overview").Range("C17:C33").Copy
        Sheets("calculator").Range("B11.B27").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If

    '---------copying L3000 with C120 -----------------------------------
    If x = "L3000" And y = "C120" Then
        Sheets("overview").Range("B45:B61").Copy
        Sheets("calculator").Range("B11.B27").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If

    '----------copying L3000 with C250 ------------------------------------
    If x = "L3000" And y = "C250" Then
        Sheets("overview").Range("C45:C61").Copy
        Sheets("calculator").Range("B11.B27").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If

    '-----------copying L3000 with C180 ------------------------------------
    If x = "L3000" And y = "C180" Then
        Sheets("overview").Range("D45:D61").Copy
        Sheets("calculator").Range("B11.B27").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by pictures. Possibly show a screenshot. Images are objects overlayed above spreadsheet grid. You will need to access such objects and copy and paste/remove them across sheets.

Comment: The image format is .JPEG if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you need to know the position of the image regarding to the cells underneath.

Deletes all pictures from a worksheet which have their top left part intersecting with a given range:

```
Dim s As Shape, rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:B2")

    For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If Intersect(rng, s.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing Then
            'do nothing
        Else
            s.Delete
        End If
    Next s
```

Copy a picture and aligns it to a cell within a worksheet:

```
Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Copy Destination:=Worksheets(2).Cells(1, 1)
```

Comment: Hope this helps!